# BottomNavigation style

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have `BottomNavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

when I use default `styles` in manifest everything is ok:

```
<application
    android:name=".model.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

[image]

When I override default `styles` like this

```
 <style name="base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/grey_dark_bg_md</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and manifest:

```
    <application
    android:name=".model.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/base">
    <activity
        android
```

I get problems. Non active bottom navigation images cuts

[image]

whats wrong with styles?

Comment: in BottomNavigationView u take a `android:layout_Weight = "1"`

Comment: give bottom navigation static height.

Comment: i think first you remove style and check same problem occur or not !

Comment: here is good example -https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Comment: Nothing help guys

Answer (score 15):

You can set style for BottomNavigationView as below:

1. Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="BottomNavigation">
    <item name="android:background">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="itemBackground">@drawable/navigation_bar_item_bg</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/navigation_bar_txt_color</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/navigation_bar_txt_color</item>
    <item name="paddingStart">@dimen/bottom_navigation_padding</item>
    <item name="paddingEnd">@dimen/bottom_navigation_padding</item>
</style>
```

2. Apply this style to your BottomNavigationView via style attribute.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    style="@style/BottomNavigation"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

example BottomNavigationView in your xml layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
            />
```

`style` attribute can be set to 1 of these:

1. @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView
2. @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored`
3. @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.PrimarySurface
4. @style/BottomNavigation <!-- this is your custom theme

your custom BottomNavigation in "themes.xml"

```
 <style name="BottomNavigation">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
        <item name="elevation">@dimen/m3_sys_elevation_level2</item>
        <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">?attr/textAppearanceCaption</item>
        <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">?attr/textAppearanceCaption</item>
        <item name="itemRippleColor">@color/mtrl_navigation_bar_colored_ripple_color</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/mtrl_navigation_bar_colored_item_tint</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/mtrl_navigation_bar_colored_item_tint</item>
        <item name="itemPaddingTop">@dimen/m3_bottom_nav_item_padding_top</item>
        <item name="itemPaddingBottom">@dimen/m3_bottom_nav_item_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/m3_bottom_nav_min_height</item>
        <item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
        <item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
        <item name="labelVisibilityMode">labeled</item>
    </style>
```

you may need to hide label by set `labelVisibilityMode` attribute value to `unlabeled`

you may need to change attribute `itemIconTint`, `itemTextColor`, `itemTextAppearanceInactive`, `itemTextAppearanceActive`, by adding file `res/color/bottom_navigation_tint.xml` and set these attributes with this file name

```
<item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">@color/bottom_navigation_tint</item>
<item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">@color/bottom_navigation_tint</item>
<item name="itemIconTint">@color/bottom_navigation_tint</item>
<item name="itemTextColor">@color/bottom_navigation_tint</item>
```

file `res/color/bottom_navigation_tint.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" />
</selector>
```